# Im trying to reset a counter once the counter hits 10 and i cant seem to get it right.

Tags: variables, counter

Once the counter hits 10, it displays "your tickets are free". I can't figure out how to reset the counter so that another 10 clicks will display "your tickets are free"

```
Public Class Form1
Dim intCounter As Integer

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim intTicketPrice As Integer = Val(Me.txtTicketNum.Text) * 8
    intCounter = intCounter + 1

    If intCounter = 10 Then
        Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets are free!!!"

    ElseIf intTicketPrice Then
        Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets cost: " & intTicketPrice & " Dollars"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    intCounter = 0
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add `intCounter = 0` inside of your if statement, after you output your text. So:

```
If intCounter = 10 Then
    Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets are free!!!"
    intCounter = 0
ElseIf intTicketPrice Then
    Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets cost: " & intTicketPrice & " Dollars"
End If
```

Alternately, you can get by without ever resetting the counter and instead perform a modulus operation on the counter -

```
If (intCounter % 10) = 0 Then
    Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets are free!!!"
ElseIf intTicketPrice Then
    Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets cost: " & intTicketPrice & " Dollars"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are expecting too much from .Net today :) You did not set the counter to 0 in your code

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim intCounter As Integer

        Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
            Dim intTicketPrice As Integer = Val(Me.txtTicketNum.Text) * 8
            intCounter = intCounter + 1

            If intCounter = 10 Then
                Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets are free!!!"
                intCounter = 0
            ElseIf intTicketPrice Then
                Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets cost: " & intTicketPrice & " Dollars"
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            intCounter = 0
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer before??

Comment: @geedubb It is an obvious problem, and I think we both answered at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Vb forms app. I think you just need to reset your intCounter inside your condition like this:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim intTicketPrice As Integer = Val(Me.txtTicketNum.Text) * 8
    intCounter = intCounter + 1

    If intCounter = 10 Then
        Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets are free!!!"
        intCounter = 0
    ElseIf intTicketPrice Then
        Me.lblFeed.Text = "Your tickets cost: " & intTicketPrice & " Dollars"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    intCounter = 0
End Sub
```